# OpenCV: Extract significant weather over an area from a weather map

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, maps, weather

I would like to extract significant weather over an area from a weather map.

This is what the map looks like:

[image: This is what the map looks like]

The black "clouds like" lines define several areas in which different types of weather phenomena will occur. The blue dashed area labeled "1" is the same type of area but refers to the legend of the map, on the right top side.

I already managed to extract all the contours (in green). That's pretty much all I can do for now because I just discovered OpenCV. (Please be kind if I missed anything.)

I assume the next step is to look in which areas the place I am interested in is located. And then try to retrieve all the significant weather symbols located inside. But I definitely do know how to do that for the moment.

The constants in this project are :

- The map will always be centered and zoomed in the exact same way.
- The region I am interested in will always be the same (the red circle that I drew with paint).

The variables of this project are :

- Between two different maps, the shapes of the significant weather areas will completely change.

Significant weather symbols in the areas will, of course, also change.

Those maps are named `TEMSI`. If someone knows a different way to use computer vision to do the job I want to do, please let me know.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/beginner-extract-significant-weather-over-an-area-from-a-weather-map/6261

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.